# constant_score query does not support query in the code

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

"constant score query doesn't support query" error is coming when i am trying to run the following code.

```
client.search({
    index: ['index1','index2'],
    body: {
        from: 0, size: 20,
        query: {
            "constant_score": {
                boost: 1.0,
                "query": {
                    query_string: {
                        query: str,
                        fields: ['field_1']
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
});
```

Comment: For me, I was using an existing code base and the problem was I was running ES 6.x when I should've been using 5.6 (which *does* support this query type)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`constant_score` query wraps another query. It either accepts another `query` or `filter` . Wrap `query_string` in `filter` instead of `query`.

Try using the below:

```
client.search({
    index: ['index1','index2'],
    body: {
        from: 0, size: 20,
        query: {
            "constant_score": {
                boost: 1.0,
                filter: {
                   query_string: {
                       query: str,
                       fields: ['field_1']
                   }
                }                
            }
        }
    },
});
```

Comment: Updated my answer. Check now.